# Python: Extract integers from string based on position of specific letters

Tags: python, string

New to Python

Scenario

1. A string is a combination of letters and digits.
2. There is always an integer following a letter. But the number of digits of an integer varies.
3. For letter "A", there is a pattern to locate its position. For example, if I replace all letters in the string by a delimiter, such as commas, "A" is always on the position of multiple of 3. I have figured a way to extract the integers that following "A".
4. However, for letter "B", there is no pattern where in the string it might appear.

My Goal

1. Extract all integers following letter "A" and "B", respectively.
2. Sum them after extraction, respectively.

Trial and Error

The way I handled "A" pattern is to use modulus operation (%) to achieve my goal

```
s = 'A4B2d2A14d3B11A20B10d10'
s_replace = s.replace('A', ',').replace('B', ',').replace('d', ',')[1:]
test_n = [int(n) for n in s_replace.split(',') if n.isdigit()]
test_Asum = sum(test_n[i] for i in range(len(test_n)) if i % 3 == 0)

print(test_Asum)
# 38
```

Please help with "B" issue. I can find the index of "B" in the string. However, how could I extract how ever many digits starting from the index of "B"?

```
test_B_index = [Bindx for Bindx, char in enumerate(s) if char == "B"]
print(test_B_index)
# [2, 11, 17]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this without the *re* module or, indeed, any other imports as follows:

```
s = 'A4B2d2A14d3B11A20B10d10'

def getsum(s, c):
    total = 0
    for t in s.split(c):
        offset = 0
        for v in t:
            if v.isdecimal():
                offset += 1
            else:
                break
        if offset > 0:
            total += int(t[:offset])
    return total

for k in 'AB':
    print(k, getsum(s, k))
```

**Output:**

```
A 38
B 23
```

Comment: Thanks @DarkKnight This is a more generic solution to my original problem. Using the function `getsum()` , I do not need to import modules and distinguish different ways to get the sum of 'A' digits or sum of 'B' digits. May I ask why use `isdecimal()` instead of `isdigit()` in this case?

Comment: @JaneLu isdigit() will return True for characters such as a ² (superscript 2) whereas isdecimal() is more constrained. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isdecimal#str.isdecimal

Answer (score 2):

My favorite way to extract things is to use regex.
Here an example in your case.
I hope it helps.

```
import re
s = 'A4B2d2A14d3B11A20B10d10'
m = re.findall(r'B([0-9]+)', s)
print(m)
#['2', '11', '10']
print(sum([int(n) for n in m]))
#23
```

Comment: Thanks, @Pauly! I am wondering if there is any other way that using just buildin method to solve this problem.